# React native error - expected a string or a class but got object

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native. I was trying to write simple programs found from tutorials in order to familiar with react-native environment. I have researched on the same bug on stackoverflow itself and couldn't find any helpful solution, that's the reason I am writing again.

I was referring to the following tutorial

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/getting-started-with-react-native-in-2019-build-your-first-app-a41ebc0617e2

Following is the code that I have used. 
Created a new class named EmojiDict.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

class EmojiDict extends Component {
state = {
    '': ' Smiley',
    '': ' Rocket',
    '⚛️': '⚛️ Atom Symbol'
};

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container} >
            <Text>this.state[''] </Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
},
instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});
```

Then modified the App.js class as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import EmojiDict from './src/components/EmojiDict';

export default class App extends Component {
render() {
    return <EmojiDict />;
  }
}
```

I have tried various examples and nothing worked when the App.js class gets modified. I am not able to go forward due to this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like you forgot to export the `EmojiDict` component

instead of `class EmojiDict extends Component {`

try

```
export default class EmojiDict extends Component {
```

may resolve this issue

Comment: Thanks Adarsh. That resolved the issue and would like to clarify that export default has to be used with all the classes defining.

Comment: yes, we need to exoprt a class component in-order to use it in other components, please refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Thanks a lot Adarsh for the reference.